# how do i click on a link and that link keeps a class untill i click on another one?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

hi i was wondering how do i click on a link that keeps a class until i click on another upon which it will remove the class from that and the one that i just clicked will have the class in return?

```
//animation for secondary content pics
$('#small li').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('small_list_hover');
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('small_list_hover');
});

$("h4").append('<em> Image 1</em>').show();

$("#small a").click(function () {
    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");
    $('li').removeClass('small_li_hover');
    $('this').addClass('small_li_hover');
    $('#largeImg').hide().fadeIn(1000).attr({
        src: largePath,
        alt: largeAlt
    });
    $("h4 em").html(" " + largeAlt + " ");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#small a").click(function () {
    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");



    //$('li').removeClass('small_li_hover'); 
    // $('this').addClass('small_li_hover'); // your problem is here....
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('small_li_hover')
           .siblings().removeClass('small_li_hover');


    $('#largeImg').hide().fadeIn(1000).attr({
        src: largePath,
        alt: largeAlt
    });
    $("h4 em").html(" " + largeAlt + " ");
    return false;
});
```

---

> Hi Reigel, i tried it but it doesnt
>   work. When i hover off the link it the
>   class removes itself!

Well, I'm not surprised. So, how about we do it this way,

changed,

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('small_li_hover')
       .siblings().removeClass('small_li_hover');
```

to something like,

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('small_li_active')
       .siblings().removeClass('small_li_active');
```

then on your css, if you have something like,

```
.small_li_hover {
   color: red;
}
```

changed it to

```
.small_li_active,
.small_li_hover {
   color: red;
}
```

## [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/m8yY8/)

Comment: Hi Reigel, i tried it but it doesnt work. When i hover off the link it the class removes itself!

Comment: I changed it and now the hover doesnt work like no class is applied. I should point out that the the links are images! If that makes any difference :D

Comment: @Nash - i think problem lies in this line $('li').removeClass('small_li_hover');  
$('this').addClass('small_li_hover'); you are removing class from 'li' and on click event adding it to 'a' tag.so make sure that whether you have to add and remove class from 'a' or 'li'.

Comment: @NASH - it may be something wrong with your css, [look at this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/m8yY8/)

Comment: thank you thank you thank you Reigel. it works!!! yay. Do you mind telling me whats exactly going on?? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: I could, but maybe later, I'll just update this post and put some comments on it. I'll be out now cause it's dinner time here. :) Well, I'm glad I could help. And don't forget to accept correct answers - it's how StackOverflow works.. cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Could you do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a").click(function() {
      $("a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
   });
});
```

Comment: I'm quite fascinated about the up-votes, and yes that's answer, but I hope at least it answers the problem based on the codes provided by the OP. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
 $("a").click(function(){
   $("a.active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LJ6L5/)

according to question it should be like
`$("#small a").click(function () {

     var largePath = $(this).attr("href");

      var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");

      $('li').removeClass('small_li_hover');

      $(this).parents('li').addClass('small_li_hover');

      $('#largeImg').hide().fadeIn(1000).attr({

        src: largePath,

        alt: largeAlt

    });

    $("h4 em").html(" " + largeAlt + " ");

    return false;

});`